# IronSource Rewards Video load second time

Tags: rewardedvideoad, ironsource

I'm using IronSource for mediating rewards video. The first time it works OK but there's no way of loading the reward video second time without killing the app.

I checked their SDK and there's no "loadReward" or "requestReward" in their API. The first video loads automatically when 
`IronSource.init(context, mAppKey, IronSource.AD_UNIT.REWARDED_VIDEO)` is called.

How can I load the second reward video?

Answer (score 0):

show RewardVideo function:

```
IronSource.showRewardedVideo();
```

---

Q: How to get Reward?

A:

First `implements RewardedVideoListener`

```
@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdRewarded(Placement placement) 
{
  String rewardName = placement.getRewardName();
  int rewardAmount = placement.getRewardAmount();
}
```